# Researching Sorting Methods For LARGE files

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting, unix

I have decided to, as side project, try and write a sorting method for large files. Unfortunately, I only have my 4 core laptop available for the research right now. For data, I am only using characters for each record. A typical record looks like this:

```
AAAAM_EL,QMOIXYGB,LAD_HNTU,BYFKKHWY,AVVCIXMC,KWVGCIUB,YWD_LQNU,HDTKUFK_,W_E_LT_M,MW_HEQKE,VHEDHK_U,SAIUAVGH,DQTSMK_L,RNUBFKUX,OXEVMHNR,EMEEJHJB,BKYQWYAP,MKMWKAAT,MIAEDTDY,RANAGVOM
```

All the fields are randomly generated. However, I am only sorting using the complete record as the key.  A file containing 1 million records equals 181Million bytes. I have noticed the following on my laptop:

1. using a unix shell and executing unix sort command against the file, it takes approximately 15 to 22 seconds to sort and write the file back to disk as another file.
2. I tried using the unix sort command with the parallel=cores option but that would not work in my widows-bash.
3. Using a quick sort algorithm I implemented in java: It takes 3 seconds to read the file into memory, sort it and write back out to a new file.
4. Using an experimental multi-threaded java application that I implemented takes as long as the "unix sort" command took.

Does anyone have some reliable approximate times for sorting a file this size? I plan on sorting much larger files once I study the multi-threaded approach that I have currently implemented. It needs a lot of improvement I am sure. However I need some good target times to try and achieve. Does anyone know of such target times. Any examples on the net , or any sorting research papers that would give me a hint as to how much time it should take.

Comment: I don't know if the unix sort is the same as gnu sort. The gnu sort is a large program, mostly due to all the command line options. Mutli-threading is only used on the initial pass that reads in large "chunks" of data, sorts the chunks, and writes one temporary file for each chunk. Each chunk can be around 1GB if there's enough ram. It then repeatedly performs a 16 way (16 is the default, this can be overridden) merge on the temporary files until it determines that it's reached the final merge step, in which case it merges the final set of temp files to the specified output file.

Comment: Continuing, for a 181 MB file (assuming there's enough ram for this), gnu sort would just read the file as a single chunk, sort the chunk, and write a sorted file, no external merge sort involved.